# problem deploying websharper F# web application

Tags: f#, websharper

I am trying the websharper demonstrations, however I get the following error:-

HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Changing the configuration to 'classic' I get a new error

Could not find file '..bin\WebSharper.info'

I am confused by the IIS settings.
How should I proceed?

Comment: Drop us an email at support at websharper.com and please mention which versions are you using.

Comment: Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

    support@websharper.com

Message will be retried for 1 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect

Comment: The correct email address is websharper-support at intellifactory.com - be sure to attach your web.config as well (or preferably the entire application as a zip).

Comment: Pardon me, it should have read websharper-support at intellifactory.com. Posting your code would be very helpful, and by using email it can remain confidential. Otherwise there is always the bugs.intellifactory.com bugtracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed in subsequent version of Websharper